# c++ program compile no reference to main

Tags: c++

i am trying to compile my c++ program and I am receiving this error.

```
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -o main.o account.o checkingaccount.o savingsaccount.o -o main
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is the makefile I am using:

```
all: main

main: main.o account.o checkingaccount.o savingsaccount.o
        g++ -o main.o account.o checkingaccount.o savingsaccount.o -o main

main.o: main.cpp checkingaccount.h savingsaccount.h account.h
        g++ -c main.cpp

account.o: account.cpp account.h
        g++ -c account.cpp

checkingaccount.o: checkingaccount.cpp checkingaccount.h account.h
        g++ -c checkingaccount.cpp

savingsaccount.o: savingsaccount.cpp savingsaccount.h account.h
        g++ -c savingsaccount.cpp
~
```

Comment: Oops: `g++ -o main.o account.o checkingaccount.o savingsaccount.o -o main` -- two `-o` options?

Comment: does your `main.c` has a `main` function? probably not. But hey where's the code?

Comment: And your `main.cpp` file contains a function with the signature `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`?

Comment: @FredLarson got the mistake. Two `-o` options: last overrides the first but `main.o` isn't taken into account in the link process.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
g++ -o main.o account.o checkingaccount.o savingsaccount.o -o main
```

... shouldn't have `-o` at the beginning. This specifies `main.o` as the name of the output file and does not link it. The second `-o` overrides this, but the file still isn't linked. Assuming `main.cpp` has your `int main()` function, you're not linking it in.